# How to improve multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to run some experiments for my computer laboratories. Simply said, I have to run an algorithm 10 times and write down the results. Then I have to change the parameters of the algorithm an run the experiment again. I wanted to run that algorithm in multiple thread to save some time. However I only managed to save about a minute.

Here's the method responsible for said multithreading:

```
public void runExperiment() {
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ArrayList<Callable<Double>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        AssignmentProblemSolution initialSolution = new AssignmentProblemSolution(filePath);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfExecutions; i++) {
            callables.add(new SimulatedAnnealing(MAX_ITER, N, Temperature, Alpha, initialSolution.newInstance()));
        }


        List<Future<Double>> futures = null;
        try {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfExecutions; i++) {
            try {
                valuesOfSolutions[i] = futures.get(i).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            average += valuesOfSolutions[i];
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!executorService.awaitTermination(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }

        average /= numberOfExecutions;

        final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        timeElapsed = (double) (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    }
```

Here is the *call()* method from *SimulatedAnnealing* class:

```
@Override
    public Double call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.maximalNumberOfOuterIterations; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.numberOfInnerIterations; j++) {
                Solution newSolution = currentSolution.findSolutionFromNeighbourhood();

                if (currentSolution.getValue() > newSolution.getValue()) {
                    currentSolution = newSolution;
                } else if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(1) < Math.exp((currentSolution.getValue() - newSolution.getValue()) / this.temperature)) {
                    currentSolution = newSolution;
                }
            }

            this.temperature *= this.alpha;
        }

        return currentSolution.getValue();
    }
```

The *findSolutionFromNeighbourhood()* method return a new solution:

```
public Solution findSolutionFromNeighbourhood() {
    return new AssignmentProblemSolution(this);
}

private AssignmentProblemSolution(AssignmentProblemSolution assignmentProblemSolution) {
        this.size = assignmentProblemSolution.getSize();
        this.costs = assignmentProblemSolution.getCosts();
        this.assignments = assignmentProblemSolution.findAssignmentsMatrixFromNeighbourhood();
        this.value = computeValue();
    }
```

Getter for *costs* copies the *costs* array with *Arrays.copyOf()*. Similary *findAssignmentMatrixFromNeighbourhood()* uses *Arrays.copyOf()* and then swaps two elements.

How can I improve my code, so that I can shave some time off running this experiment.

Comment: Change `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` to use something other than `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`, try and experiment with it little, see where it might help.  Remember though, more threads doesn't always mean more done in less time

Comment: Also, If you suspect the code is inefficient try running a sampler during program execution to get a feeling in which methods the most execution time is spent.

Comment: Questions about improving otherwise working code may be better suited for [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.